# Writing results of a python script to CSV

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I'm using this Amazon reviews scraper I found on Github: https://github.com/philipperemy/amazon-reviews-scraper

```
        for review in reviews_list:
             rating = review.find(attrs={'data-hook': 'review-star-rating'}).attrs['class'][2].split('-')[-1]
             body = review.find(attrs={'data-hook': 'review-body'}).text
             date = review.find(attrs={'data-hook': 'review-date'}).text
             title = review.find(attrs={'data-hook': 'review-title'}).text

             logging.info('***********************************************')
             logging.info(title)
             logging.info(date)
             logging.info(rating)
             logging.info(body)
             logging.info('***********************************************\n')
             reviews.append({'title': title,
                             'rating': rating,
                             'body': body,
                             'product_id': product_id
                            })

              return reviews
```

I want those results to be sent to a CSV file. But I'm just a beginner with Python so I'm not entirely sure. I'm using Python on Windows.

With the help of Akshat I've got this, but I'm not sure it's correct:

```
        for review in reviews_list:
            rating = review.find(attrs={'data-hook': 'review-star-rating'}).attrs['class'][2].split('-')[-1]
            body = review.find(attrs={'data-hook': 'review-body'}).text
            date = review.find(attrs={'data-hook': 'review-date'}).text
            title = review.find(attrs={'data-hook': 'review-title'}).text

from csv import DictWriter

with open('results.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['title', 'date', 'rating', 'body']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()

    for review in reviews: 
        writer.writerow(review)
```

Comment: [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: That is true. I updated my post to reflect it. I've just been trying anything since yesterday and have really gotten nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
    writer.writerow(title, date, rating, body)
```

`writerow` expects a sequence. Do this instead:

```
    writer.writerow([title, date, rating, body])
```

That line needs to be inside a loop through `reviews`.

Comment: Thanks. So I've tried to replace the whole logging sequence with the below but it doesn't seem to work. Should it?     import csv
with open('results.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow([title, date, rating, body])

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the error pointed out by [@BoarGules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50038240/4797454). I would suggest you to explore [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) from CSV module

```
from csv import DictWriter

with open('results.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['title', 'date', 'rating', 'body']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()

    for review in reviews: 
        writer.writerow(review)
```

Comment: I've added that to the script and it's telling me Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "amazon_comments_scraper.py", line 3, in <module>
    from core_extract_comments import *
  File "C:\Users\jrath\ars\core_extract_comments.py", line 74
    import DictWriter from csv
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: check now, sequence of import statement had an issue

Comment: I think I'm doing something very wrong, where should this go in my script and what should I replace with it?

Comment: I updated my original post to reflect what I have now. i'm still getting an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "amazon_comments_scraper.py", line 3, in <module>
    from core_extract_comments import *
  File "C:\Users\jrath\ars\core_extract_comments.py", line 59
    from csv import DictWriter
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: you still the need the code you had in reviews.append. my suggestions only related to generating CSV